# mysql 5.6+ lamp AMI

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, lamp

I used couple of ec2 instance, ebs etc.
Now I need to configure new system, and I think AMI search sucks!

What I need is

Ubuntu,64-bit, ebs mount, lamp+phpmyadmin, MySql Version > 5.6 .

Is there any better search interface which gives detail version of each AMI? Or if you have used above mentioned AMI, can you provide details?

thanks

raxit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MySQL 5.6 has only just reached GA on February 5](http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/press/1904335). It will take some time (days or perhaps weeks) before any packagers have stable builds available, because changing the MySQL version affects many other system packages.

It will be days or weeks beyond that before Amazon AMIs become available.